# Prevent enter from writing new line in content edititable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

How can I prevent the user from writing a new line with the enter key in a contenteditable div?

So far I have tried (the id of my editable div is `editable`:

```
$('#editable').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However this does not work.

Is this possible using JS and jQuery?

> Edit

I have been informed that pressing enter does not insert a new line so I have put a picture showing when happens when I press enter inside the editable div.

I would like code to remain on one line basically, even if the user presses enter.

[image]

Comment: ENTER doesn't create a new-line into a contenteditable div element. It creates `<div>` or `p` element, depending on the implementation, and the value of `execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator')` if set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `keyup`, use `keydown`.

```
const ediatble = document.querySelector('#editable');
ediatble.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault();

  }
});
```

[See example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp2hargn/)